# How to loop data.table function through table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to get the moving average of all columns in my data set. I've found the following code to work to achieve this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)  
setkey(data1,column1, column2)
data1[,column3_l10:=as.numeric(lag(slide_dbl(column3, mean, .before = 10))),by=column2]
data1[,column4_l10:=as.numeric(lag(slide_dbl(column4, mean, .before = 10))),by=column2]
data1[,column5_l10:=as.numeric(lag(slide_dbl(column5, mean, .before = 10))),by=column2]
....
```

However there are many numeric columns in my dataset and I would like to create a function that would iterate through all the columns and get the moving average rather than adding them one by one. I've tried the following code however am receiving an error.

```
columns <- colnames(data1)

mean_func <- function(data, columns, group) {
  for(i in columns) {
    df[,paste0(get(i), "_l10") := as.numeric(lag(slide_dbl(get(i), mean, .before = 10))), by=group]
  }
}

mean_func(data = data1, columns = cols, group = "column2")


Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, :=, `:=`(...) and let(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Apologies in advance if my question is not correctly formatted.

Comment: What’s wrong with `lapply`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Arif Ahmed! This is a good start to your first question, though I request that you be specific about non-base packages. I'm guessing `slider::slide_dbl`, and I _hope_ `dplyr::lag` since `stats::lag` is almost certainly not going to do what you need. Since you're using `data.table`, is there a reason you're using `dplyr::lag` instead of the more native/canonical `data.table::shift(., type="lag")`?

Comment: Further, having sample data can be useful, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for examples of using `dput` or `data.table(..)` or similar to provide unambiguous sample data in your question. I think what you need is something like `nms <- c("column3", "column4", ...); data1[, paste0(nms, "_l10") := lapply(.SD, function(z) shift(slide_dbl(z, mean, .before=10), type="lag")), .SDcols = nms, by = "column2"]`.

Comment: The `nms` I created there _might_ be created automatically with something like `nms <- sapply(data1, is.numeric); nms <- names(nms[nms])`, I'm not certain. There are likely other ways it can be made fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'll keep in mind to add the additional info in my questions. Was not aware of the data.table::shift function. The lapply function is what I was looking for. What is the .SD argument in the lapply function doing in this case?